# svn:how to get the changed files within specific date?

Tags: shell, svn, stat

I want to make a stat via svn,and the input and output like this:
**input**:svn url,statDate,endDate
**output**:
person1 20Lines
persion2 30Lines

eg: my.sh http://svn.xxx.com/trunck/xxx/xxx/test.php 2014-12-01 2014-12-10

I use the shell script,and my idea like follows:
1.svn co the whole project
2.get the changed files within a specific date based on the giving url
3.use the command 'svn blame [file url]' get the changed infos by person

but now I don't know how to get the changed files in a directory within a specific date

please give me any ideas,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `svn status`, as this only shows if a file has changed in the working copy, whereas you are looking for commit info. You can, however, use

```
svn log -vq -r {2014-12-01}:{2014-12-10} http://svn.xxx.com/trunck/xxx/xxx/test.php
```

for your purposes. The `-v` adds information on the changed paths, the `-q` suppresses the commit message and only shows the changed paths.

You can then parse this output for the changed paths, user, and revision, and then use `svn diff` to find out for a given path how many lines were changed by that user in the specified revision.